# How to use mod_rewrite and Url redirection at same time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a url like this

```
post_article.php?url=how-to-use-mod-rewrite
```

I am using mod_rewrite to make it

```
post/how-to-use-mod-rewrite
```

Code I am using in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ post_article.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Now both of this urls will give the same content, which is not good in SEO point of view.
**How I can redirect all those old urls to new url**.

ie post_article.php?url=any-value to  post/anyvalue

Comment: I don't want to read that article if you're on here, asking this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fi/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to help search engines understand duplicate content, if SEO is your sole concern.

Comment: that is a good solution. But it is an established site with plenty of in linking. so canonical URLS is not a good solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect ^post_article.php?url=.*$ post/$1
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ post_article.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Try it.

Comment: `Redirect ^post_article\.php?url=.*$ post/$1`

Answer (score -1):

Just create a function to rewrite all your links in your articles, and search engines will never be able to find the old url scheme.

Comment: You don't know if other sites already link to those pages. Also, the links might already be in the index. And to be honest, this is just not answering the actual question.